# Is this the correct way to atomically read and write a bool?

Tags: c++, multithreading, atomic, c++98

A boolean flag is toggled by two threads. Does the following code make sense?

```
static bool ATOMIC_BOOL_READ( volatile bool& var )
{
    return __sync_fetch_and_or(&var, 0);
}

static void ATOMIC_BOOL_WRITE(volatile bool& var, bool newval )
{
    __sync_bool_compare_and_swap( &var, !newval, newval);
}
```

Note a few things:

- I am passing in a bool reference. Make sense?
- For kick's sake, I am also declaring it volatile.
- The functions are static

Update:

The fundamental question I want to ask is:
Whats the difference between atomicity and memory barrier? If Thread A is executing an *atomic builtin* on variable foo, then Thread B cannot do ANYTHING on variable foo; hence creating a memory barrier?

Comment: It doesn't make a lot of sense to declare a function argument `volatile` since it is already confined to one thread by means of being allocated on the stack.

Comment: The above comment is wrong. var is NOT on the stack...

Comment: @AdamZalcman It's a reference to a `volatile`.  But it probably isn't necessary.  If the two `__sync` functions do what they're supposed to, then there shouldn't be any problems, `volatile` or no.  And if they don't, `volatile` probably won't help.

Comment: I don't see where the bool variable is declared, it might be allocated on the heap. And a local variable on a stack of a thread is by no means "confined", as soon as you take the address or pass it as reference to another thread it might be very well changed from "outside". But I agree it is most likely unnecessary to declare it `volatile`, as long as you use the `__sync_*` functions to access it at least.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Atomics are intrinsically **non-portable** and these are GCC extensions that might not exist anymore in the future and won't work on other compilers.

You should read the rest of the answer only once you understood completely the above statement.

A notable fact is that ALL machines existing have always guaranteed that access to data up to a certain **size** is atomic. This comes from the basic notion that data in memory and in the system bus is transfered with a certain **granularity**. A boolean should definitively be atomic in most machines, so:

```
bool ATOMIC_BOOL_READ(volatile bool* b) {
    bool v = *b;
    __sync_synchronize(); // ensure value pushed to memory
    return v;
}

void ATOMIC_BOOL_WRITE(volatile bool* b, bool v) {
    __sync_synchronize(); // read will return fresh value
   *b = v;
}
```

That is probably the reason why GCC does not provide simple load/store special atomic operations: they are already supposed to be atomic.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5883/discussion-between-giovanni-funchal-and-kostolma)

Comment: These are obsoleted by `__atomic_load_n(&var, __ATOMIC_SEQ_CST)` (or ACQUIRE if you only need that), avoiding the need for draining the store buffer on both load and store on ISAs like x86.  https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fatomic-Builtins.html.  Or for the store, `__sync_lock_release` if you only need `__ATOMIC_RELEASE` semantics.

Answer (score 5):

`__sync_bool_compare_and_swap` is correct, but possibly much more expensive than necessary.

It depends what you need. `__sync_lock_test_and_set` will be cheaper (and guaranteeed to be atomic), but it does not report back if the operation was "successful" insofar as the value is what was expected (it's always "successful" anyway, and you do get the value back too, it just doesn't *fail* if it's not what you said). However, this is some information that is not always interesting.

Instead of the atomic builtins, you could use `std::atomic<bool>` if you compile in C++0x mode, which offers `.load()` and `.store()`. These functions are possibly more efficient (either exploiting knowledge that some operation is atomic anyway, or inserting barriers, or using special operations, or whatever), and your code is more portable (and more obvious).

Further, on pretty much every architecture, you can also expect (thought there is no guarantee!) a write to a bool being atomic anyway.

And... it really depends. If for example you just want to set a flag in one thread, and just want to see whether it's set in the other thread and it does not matter if it maybe takes a few more microseconds before this is realized, you can just assign the variable regardless of any atomicity.

Comment: Thanks for __sync_lock_test_and_set(); I considered using that at one point, but I do not remember why I didn't settle on it. I am dealing with a large codebase, I cannot use C++0x just yet.

Comment: @Kostolma: Then use GNU C `__atomic` builtins instead of the obsolete `__sync` builtins. (https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fatomic-Builtins.html).  Compilers which *can* support C++11 have `__atomic` which was added to expose loads and stores, not just RMWs.  e.g. `return __atomic_load_n(&var, __ATOMIC_ACQUIRE)`.  Or if you insist on `__sync` builtins, `__sync_fetch_and_add` is somewhat less bad on x86 since it can compile to a `lock xadd` instruction, but `fetch_and_or` needs a CAS retry loop.  Or volatile read + barrier works.

Answer (score 5):

You only need atomics for the read-modify-write family of actions. Isolated reads and writes are already atomic.

Your question says the two threads "toggle" the same bool. That is not what your posted functions do -- if you combine those functions to perform a toggle, it *still* isn't thread-safe.

Why not use `std::atomic_int`?

`i=0;` is thread-safe, `i=i+1;` isn't because if another thread does the same thing at the same time, `i` might end up being incremented only once instead of twice. This is a read-modify-write and an example problem sequence is `(read1,read2,modify1,write1,modify2,write2)` for threads 1 and 2. So far, so standard.

Now can you see why this also isn't thread-safe?

```
bool x = ATOMIC_BOOL_READ (&b);
x = !x;
ATOMIC_BOOL_WRITE (&b, x);
```

Your functions add **no** thread safety whatsoever. You could write a function

```
bool atomic_toggle_and_return_new_value (bool * b) { ... }
```

based on compare-and-swap or test-and-set, say. For more complicated cases where "both threads read and write to the *same* bool you need the readers and writers to cooperatively synchronise on some critical section (or look into lock-free and wait-free algorithms).

Comment: There are a couple of things I do not understand:
* What you mean by "You only need atomics for the read-modify-write family of actions. Isolated reads and writes are already atomic". What are these read-modify-write family you speak of? Isn't it redundant to say that "isolated reads and writes are already atomtic"; these built-ints garantee.

* 
More importantly, what did you mean by "if you combine those functions to perform a toggle, it still isn't thread-safe". Maybe "toggle" was the wrong word, but both threads read and write to the *same* bool.

Comment: `i=0` is thread-safe for `volatile int i`, on compilers that at least de-facto support `volatile`  loads/stores as atomic for multithreading for narrow-enough types.  (It's UB in C++11, [but was used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4557979/when-to-use-volatile-with-multi-threading/58535118#58535118) before C++11 `std::atomic` made it obsolete to roll your own.)  **But `volatile` does *not* give you memory *ordering*, only atomicity** - it's like `atomic_load(&var, std::memory_order_relaxed)` so isn't usable for checking a `buffer_ready` flag without separate barriers.

Comment: The obsolete GNU C `__sync` builtins are all RMWs with a full barrier, like `memory_order_seq_cst`, so the OP *was* getting ordering from their inefficient implementations.